# How to ignore certain PCH defines in some classes? (Cannot find interface declaration for)

Tags: objective-c, pch

For example, I created a category `UILabel+AALabel.h`

And has added it into PCH: `#import "UILabel+AALabel.h"`

But this obviously causes an error in my category file (UILabel+AALabel.h), because it attempts to import itself: 
"Cannot find interface declaration for 'UILabel'".

Is there any way to keep using PCH on a project-level, without having such issues? Maybe there are directives which check the file to which its (pch) contents are imported?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you included `#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>` in your category header?

Comment: Don't put it in the PCH file, it's lazy, put it where you actually need it.

Comment: Yes, I included and I need it for optimizing